# How to make container fixed. the container wont resize after clicking the widgets inside it . Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design, flutter-container

I am having trouble with my design as i want this container as a background for my dropdowns and textformfield. but its changing its size once i click on description or dates.
Please help how to make it fixed. i have attached some screenshots also of before and after clicking the formfield.

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              border: Border.all(
                // color: Colors.black,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  width: 1.0),
            ),
            // color: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.5),
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 350, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 440),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 52,
                      width: 270,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                          // color: Colors.black,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Select Chapter'),
                          items: chapteritemlist.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item['chapterId'].toString(),
                              child: Text(item['chapter'].toString()),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownchapterdisplay = newVal;
                            });
                            chaptid = newVal;
                            print(chaptid);
                            getAllMember();
                          },
                          value: dropdownchapterdisplay,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 52,
                      width: 270,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                          // color: Colors.black,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Select Member'),
                          items: memberitemlist.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item['id'].toString(),
                              child: Text(
                                item['name'].toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 9,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownmemberdisplay = newVal;
                            });
                            memberid = newVal;
                          },
                          value: dropdownmemberdisplay,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 48,
                      width: 270,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.

                        // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: description,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Description",
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 88,
                      width: 270,
                      child: DateTimeFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'MM DD, YYYY',
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.event_note),
                          labelText: 'Select Date',
                        ),
                        mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                        validator: (e) => (e?.day ?? 0) == 1
                            ? 'Please not the first day'
                            : null,
                        onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                 Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              saveRequestModel = SaveClass();
                              saveRequestModel.Description = description.text;
                              saveRequestModel.UserName = global_Email;
                              saveRequestModel.Id = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.toFId = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.ToSelf = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.TranType = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.ToId = 6;
                              saveRequestModel.MeetingDate = '2022-10-02';
                              print(saveRequestModel.ToId);

                              SaveService saveService = SaveService();
                              saveService.save(saveRequestModel).then((value) {
                                print("data saved");
                              });
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                            ),
                            // color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                            // textColor: Colors.white,
                            // elevation: 5,
                            child: const Text('Save',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              ),
                              // color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                              // textColor: Colors.white,
                              // elevation: 5,
                              child: const Text('Check Report',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                            ),
                          ))
                    ]),
                  ),
                
              ],
            )),
```

Here is the full code.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_field/date_field.dart';

//import 'package:saarthi/api/saarthi_meeting/chapter_api.dart';
import 'package:saarthi/api/saarthi_meeting/sarthi_services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:saarthi/api/saarthi_meeting/save_button.dart';

import 'package:saarthi/model/saarthi_meeting/saarthi_model.dart';
import 'package:saarthi/model/saarthi_meeting/save_model.dart';
import 'package:saarthi/variables.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Saarthi_Meeting());
}

class Saarthi_Meeting extends StatelessWidget {
  Saarthi_Meeting({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  String value = "";
  String url = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: datadisplay(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class datadisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  const datadisplay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<datadisplay> createState() => _datadisplayState();
}

class _datadisplayState extends State<datadisplay> {
  final SaarthiService _fetchdata = SaarthiService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/CG.png', width: 200),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        elevation: 13,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => smdesign()));
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Saarthidata>>(
            future: _fetchdata.smdata(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var data = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (data?[index].id != null) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => smdesign(),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          title: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'On Date - ${data?[index].date}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Text(
                                  'From User - ${data?[index].fromName}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Text(
                                  'To User - ${data?[index].toName}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class smdesign extends StatefulWidget {
  smdesign({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<smdesign> createState() => _smdesignState();
}

class _smdesignState extends State<smdesign> {
  String? dropdownvalue = "Self";
  String chaptervalue = "One";
  bool isVisible = false;

  //---------------------variable----------------------------------------------------API
  List chapteritemlist = [];
  var dropdownchapterdisplay;

  

  //---------------------variable----------------------------------------------------API
  List memberitemlist = [];
  var dropdownmemberdisplay;

  //------------------------------api dropdown 3 ---------------------------------
  

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------API
  //----------------------------------save-------------------save--------------------------
  late SaveClass saveRequestModel;
  var description = TextEditingController();

  //----------------------------------save-------------------save--------------------------

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllChapter();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/CG.png', width: 200),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        elevation: 13,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              border: Border.all(
                // color: Colors.black,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  width: 1.0),
            ),
            // color: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.5),
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 350, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 440),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 52,
                      width: 270,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                          // color: Colors.black,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Select Chapter'),
                          items: chapteritemlist.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item['chapterId'].toString(),
                              child: Text(item['chapter'].toString()),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownchapterdisplay = newVal;
                            });
                            chaptid = newVal;
                            print(chaptid);
                            getAllMember();
                          },
                          value: dropdownchapterdisplay,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 52,
                      width: 270,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                          // color: Colors.black,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          hint: const Text('Select Member'),
                          items: memberitemlist.map((item) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: item['id'].toString(),
                              child: Text(
                                item['name'].toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 9,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownmemberdisplay = newVal;
                            });
                            memberid = newVal;
                          },
                          value: dropdownmemberdisplay,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 48,
                      width: 270,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.

                        // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: description,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Description",
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 88,
                      width: 270,
                      child: DateTimeFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'MM DD, YYYY',
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.event_note),
                          labelText: 'Select Date',
                        ),
                        mode: DateTimeFieldPickerMode.date,
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                        validator: (e) => (e?.day ?? 0) == 1
                            ? 'Please not the first day'
                            : null,
                        onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                 Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              saveRequestModel = SaveClass();
                              saveRequestModel.Description = description.text;
                              saveRequestModel.UserName = global_Email;
                              saveRequestModel.Id = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.toFId = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.ToSelf = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.TranType = 0;
                              saveRequestModel.ToId = 6;
                              saveRequestModel.MeetingDate = '2022-10-02';
                              print(saveRequestModel.ToId);

                              SaveService saveService = SaveService();
                              saveService.save(saveRequestModel).then((value) {
                                print("data saved");
                              });
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                            ),
                            // color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                            // textColor: Colors.white,
                            // elevation: 5,
                            child: const Text('Save',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    font size: 25,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              ),
                              // color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                              // textColor: Colors.white,
                              // elevation: 5,
                              child: const Text('Check Report',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                            ),
                          ))
                    ]),
                  ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Before Image -[This is before clicking anything. The design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE5Mb.png)

After Image -[when I click on the description form field it shows like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez5sA.png)

Comment: Just wrap scaffold with singlechildlistview widget.

Comment: not working the page comes out to be blank when i use singlechildscrollview.